# What could cause kswapd to reclaim tens of GBs of file cache on a postgres machine?

Tags: memory, postgresql

Usually the size of the file cache on our managed postgres machine running in GCP is between 110GB and 120GB. Sometimes it drops by ~35GB then oscillates by 10GB for an hour or two before slowly growing back to normal size. Sometimes it drops to ~90GB before returning to a similar size over ~twenty minutes. [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wOi6.png)

I'd like to know what could cause kswapd to reclaim tens of GBs from the cache, only for it to end up as free memory.